# pyspark sql - compare first day of month with string

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column in a dataframe `firstday`, in timestamp format, looks like this `2022-03-01 00:00:00` I'm trying to pass `run_date` a string parameter at run time as filter. But the sql below didn't work. How do you achieve this? Many thanks!

Trying to convert `run_date` , which looks like `2022-03-28` to the first day of the month and use it to compare with `firstday`

```
spark.sql("select * from df where firstday = date_trunc('mon','{}')".format(run_date))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there, little formatting issues

orginal df

```
    +---+----------+
    | id|  firstday|
    +---+----------+
    |  1|2022-03-01|
    |  2|2022-03-17|
    +---+----------+
```

Apply filter

```
run_date="'2022-03-21'"
filtereddf=spark.sql(("select * from df where firstday ==date_trunc('mon',{})").format(run_date))
filtereddf.show()
```

or

```
run_date="2022-03-21"
filtereddf=spark.sql(("select * from df where firstday ==date_trunc('mon','{}')").format(run_date))
filtereddf.show()

+---+----------+
| id|  firstday|
+---+----------+
|  1|2022-03-01|
+---+----------+
```